TypeError: Could not locate class 'CNN_Encoder'. Make sure custom classes are decorated with `@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()`
I am trying to import a trained model into my flask app, but it is repeatedly showing this error,
flask app code ->
from modeldefinitions import CNN_Encoder 
encoder = tf.keras.models.load_model('output/cnn_encoder.keras')

the modeldefinitions.py file ->
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers 
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
class CNN_Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim):
        super(CNN_Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.fc = layers.Dense(embedding_dim)
        self.dropout = layers.Dropout(0.5)
    def call(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        return x

Error ->

TypeError: Could not locate class 'CNN_Encoder'. Make sure custom
classes are decorated with
@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(). Full object config:
{'module': None, 'class_name': 'CNN_Encoder', 'config': {'trainable':
True, 'dtype': 'float32'}, 'registered_name': 'CNN_Encoder',
'build_config': {'input_shape': [32, 64, 2048]}}

I tried nearly all the other stackoverflow suggestions, reinstalled tf and keras, even tried all the AI code generators, nothing seems to work. My second DL project only, so i guess I must be doing something very wrong

The problem you're facing suggests there's a serialization issue with TensorFlow when attempting to load your custom model CNN_Encoder within a Flask application.In your modeldefinitions.py file, make sure your CNN_Encoder class is decorated with @tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable() before its definition.When saving the model (cnn_encoder.keras), ensure you are saving the entire model, including its architecture and weights.When loading the model in your Flask app, make sure TensorFlow is imported and the environment is set up correctly. Here's how you should load the model
